# why Resource Barrier need before state?

Tags: directx-12

I am very very sorry for my poor english.
I have a question about directx 12 D3D12_RESOURCE_TRANSITION_BARRIER.

```
typedef struct D3D12_RESOURCE_TRANSITION_BARRIER {
  ID3D12Resource        *pResource;
  UINT                  Subresource;
  D3D12_RESOURCE_STATES StateBefore;
  D3D12_RESOURCE_STATES StateAfter;
} D3D12_RESOURCE_TRANSITION_BARRIER;
```

I think GPU will knows resource's state because StateAfter.

What's the purpose of StateBefore ?

Comment: With no prior knowledge, looks like for performance reasons: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmB2XMasz2o

Comment: no. it's about how to tracking StateBefore in multithread env.